# ajax call to a local csv file

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv

The folder structure is:
HOME\htmlhelp\wwhelp\wwhimpl\js\scripts
HOME\auxi\

I can read a csv file (located in the HOME\htmlhelp dir) from a js file located in the HOME\htmlhelp\wwhelp\wwhimpl\js\scripts dir using the following:
var file_path="../../../../../htmlhelp/rule_mapping.csv";

However, the same js file (from the same location) cannot read the same csv file in the HOME\auxi\ directory!
Am using the path as var file_path="../../../../../auxi/rule_mapping.csv";

It throws an "NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied" error. I have checked the file permissions and stuff but no luck. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within:

```
var file_path="../../../../../htmlhelp/rule_mapping.csv";
```

It's **not possible to traverse up to paths out of the root directory** where the document is located.

Assuming you work under UNIX (Linux/Mac), one solution would be to create a symbolic link on the root directory of the document, such as (executing from the scripts directory):

```
ln -s ../../../../../htmlhelp/rule_mapping.csv rule_mapping.csv
```

And changing the file_path to:

```
var file_path="./rule_mapping.csv";
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: So to say, if a webpage is served on http://example.com/index.html, this index.html (or any script called by it) can't access file paths that are above the / path of index.html.

If this page is served from /var/www/example.com/index.html, you cannot reference a file in as ../file.txt, (in /var/www/file.txt), since it's above the website root.